# Is $\frac{\left(4k-4n\right)\bmod 4N}{4}=\left(k-n\right)\bmod N$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to understand the modulo operation.

Let $$k,n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
At firt I thought:

$$\left(4k-4n\right)\bmod 4N=\left(k-n\right)\bmod N$$

But after a few simple examples I realized that this is not true.
On the other hand, for each example I find that the following statement is true:

$$\frac{\left(4k-4n\right)\bmod 4N}{4}=\left(k-n\right)\bmod N$$

Is this statement really true? If so, why?

Comment: The $k,n$ aren't serving any purpose here...your question gets simpler if you take $m=k-n$ and just speak of, say, $m\pmod N$.

Comment: To your question:  If $m=qN+r$ then $4m=q(4N)+4r$ so you just need to check the, straight forward, inequalities you need.

Comment: By the [mod distributive law:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242) $\,(4a \bmod 4n)/4 = 4(a\bmod n)/4  = a\bmod n,\,$ so what remains is straightforward.

Answer (score -1):

Let $\frac{(4k−4n)\bmod 4N}{4}=a$. Then $(4k-4n)\bmod4N=4a$ and so $4a=4k-4n+4Nm$ for some integer $m$. So dividing both sides by $4$ we get $$a=\frac{4k-4n+4Nm}{4}=k-n+Nm$$ Taking both sides $\bmod N$ we get $a=(k-n)\bmod N$ and therefore $$\frac{(4k−4n)\bmod 4N}{4}=a=(k-n)\bmod N$$